Business Vault Satellite to capture Many-to-Many relationship
We have a LINK that tracks all the Gift Cards used a By a Customer. It is a Many to Many Relationship, a Customer may use multiple Gift Cards, and a single Gift Card may be used by Used by Multiple Customers (partial balance etc.)
We need to create a Business Vault Satellite that can capture this many-to-many association as a single record. The single records should have all the Gift Cards by all the Customers that have used those Gift Cards. What is the best way to design this BV SAT?
LINK_CUSTOMER_GIFTCARD:



Customer ID
Gift Cards Acct Number




AAA
1111


BBB
1111


AAA
2222


CCC
2222


DDD
3333



Information we need to surface:



Customer IDs
Gift Cards Acct Numbers




AAA, BBB, CCC
1111;2222


DDD
3333;



Thanks,
Saqib

Your information requirement belongs in an infomart or in a so called flat-and-wide table, not in the Business Vault. "Needing to have a single record in a BV satellite" is no valid business logic and thus has no place in the Business Vault.
That being said, count yourself lucky having business people with so much interest and affinity for Data Vault. ;-)
